# Create a JSON output in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

I want to create a JSON output as shown here:
this is top1 from my source table:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wuD4qgurx5zA1bFjtYKjAEacMQlQvpZS/view?usp=sharing

and it is my table source script:

```
CREATE TABLE [Setting].[PrinterData]
(
[ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
[Name] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[ShowName] [varchar] (100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Type] [varchar] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[Data] [nvarchar] (max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[AL] [varchar] (3) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[DefaultStation] [char] (3) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[FileType] [varchar] (6) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[HandlingID] [tinyint] NULL,
[isDeleted] [bit] NULL,
[VersionNo] [tinyint] NULL,
[IsDefault] [bit] NULL,
[UpdateBy] [int] NULL,
[UpdatedDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[PectabSystemID] [tinyint] NULL,
[DataVersionNo] [tinyint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__PrinterDa__DataV__38A0BA30] DEFAULT ((1)),
[Template] [varchar] (2000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [Setting].[PrinterData] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Print_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

```
[
    {
        "DeviceID": 0,
        "Data": [
            "EP#AIRLINEID=220#HARDCODE=HDC#FONT=L",
            "LC",
            "PC",
            "PT##?E9N#@;#TICKT#CHKIN#BOARD#01011101#0205#0330E01#0415#0513#0603E42L#0705E44L#0816#0903#1010#1105G42L#1205F42L#1318F04L#1418G03L#1505#1610#1705#1808L04L#2104L19#2205#2305#2405#2605O04L#2715M04L#2815#3002N04L#3103N09L#3701#4310L39L#4406L24K58#4504#4715M38L#4810N38L#4915O39L#5011#5105F01L#5206G01L#5305#5405#5504O01L#5604N01L#5703N07L#5816#5907#6016G35L#6113F35L#6213E35L#6307M01L#6504L001L#6620#6712#6805#6907#7008L35L#7106M35L#7205N35L#7307O35L#7422B20#7522J01R#7625E56L#7725F56L#FAB5N579984#",
            "PT##?S9N#@;#TICKT#CHKIN#BOARD#01011101#0205#0340F10#0405H57L#0505H65L#0603F42F54L#0705F44F56L#0816G54L#0903#1010A54#1105H43L#1205G43L#1315G13L#1418H12L#1505#1610O45L#1705#1808O17L#1920#2020#2104#2205M28R#2305M44R#2405M62R#2520#2605P10P57L#2715P17L#2813#2901M56R#3004P32O57L#3103P34O59L#3215G16L#3315H15L#3405#3515#3601C02#3701D05#3820#3920#4020#4120#4220#4301#4406M13R#4520#4601C17#4720#4820#4920#5011#5105G10H54L#5203H10H63L#5305K45K63L#5405K14L#5504O10P54L#5604#5703#5816#5908O41L#6012H36L#6112G36L#6212F36L#6307#6420#6504#6619A26#6711#6804#6920#7020#7120#7220#7320#7420#7520#7620#7714K29L#7805K56L#7904O32O54L#8004P41L#8120#8220#8320#8420#8520#8620#8920#9020#FABRE012232#FBBRE012232#"
        ]
    }
]
```

I try using this query:

```
SELECT 
    DeviceID = CASE
                   WHEN pd.Type IN ( 'BP', 'MD' ) THEN 0
                   ELSE 1
               END,
    STRING_AGG(pd2.Data, ',')data
FROM
    Setting.PrinterData AS pd
JOIN 
    Setting.PrinterData AS pd2 ON pd2.ID = pd.ID
WHERE  
    pd.isDeleted = 0
    AND pd.al = 'ZZ'
GROUP BY 
    CASE
        WHEN pd.Type IN ( 'BP', 'MD' ) THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END 
FOR JSON AUTO
```

I got this output:

```
[{
    "DeviceID": 0,
    "data": "PT##?S9N#@;#TICKT#CHKIN#BOARD#01011101#0205#0340F10#0405H57L#0505H65L#0603F42F54L#0705F44F56L#0816G54L#0903#1010320#8420#8520#8620#8920#9020#FABRE012232#FBBRE012232#,^XA  ~TA000  ~JSN  ^LT0  ^MNN  ^MTD  ^PON  ^PMN  ^LH0,0  ^JMA  ^PR14,14  ~SD15  ^JUS  ^LRN  ^CI27  ^PA0,1,1,0  ^XZ  ^XA  ^MMT  ^PW591  ^LL1624  ^LS0\n  ^FT500,200^LOGO39\n^FO0,1184^GFA,00128,00128,00004,:Z64:\neJxjYMAO7P9DMK0BAPvqAn0=:89A8\n^FT344,236^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDFROM:$HNN - $FRANKFURT-HANN^FS\n^FT302,236^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDTO:$WWW - $ARVIDSJAUR^FS\n^FT38,946^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDAGT:$25^FS\n^FT382,1256^A0R,25,21^FH\\^FD$AC ,585^A0R,56,55^FH\\^FD$22:22^FS\n^FT72,683^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDBAG:^FS\n^FT38,667^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FD$17\/$18 $kgs^FS\n^FT38,424^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FD$11111111^FS\n^FT72,424^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FD$V223HB^FS\n^FT341,1256^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FD$JOHN HUDSON^FS\n^FT219,1484^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDSEAT^FS\n^FT38,1277^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDSEQ:$4321^FS\n^FT161,1483^A0R,56,55^FH\\^FD$3B^FS\n^BY3,9^FT54,213^B7N,9,2,,,N\n^FH\\^FDM1JOHN HUDSON         C3JIOP  HHNAJRSR 7999 56 Y12E 12   100\\5C5E00L262562^FS\n^FT72,946^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDCLS:$Y^FS\n^FT294,1256^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDFROM:$HNN^FS\n^FT294,1429^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDTO:$WWW^FS\n^FT72,1277^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDBAG:$17\/$18 $kgs^FS\n^FT513,1256^A0R,35,40^FH\\^FD$Economy^FS\n^FT341,826^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDFLIGHT TIME: $23:50^FS\n^FT302,826^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDFLIGHT DATE:$25 FEB 2020^FS\n^FT386,236^A0R,37,36^FH\\^FD$JOHN HUDSON^FS\n^FO143,235^GB112,878,8^FS\n^FO143,1250^GB112,331,8^FS\n^FT219,1298^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDZONE^FS\n^FT513,634^A0R,35,40^FH\\^FDBOARDING PASS^FS\n^FO480,0^GB0,1658,4^FS\n^FT382,826^A0R,25,24^FH\\^FDFLIGHT NUMBER:$AC $3999^FS\n^FO549,1190^GB22,0,2^FS\n^FO516,1190^GB22,0,2^FS\n^FO484,1190^GB22,0,2^FS\n^FO449,1190^GB22,0,2^F4mnzHGGGOMMcYYY4wxxhhjjDHGGGOMMcYYY4wxxngBviT\/2kgPsjfaubvOPXbutHO\/nbvuRvbZuQPPffhHN97Hm9qT587cRrf93XoDBS+XaA==:BFE1\n\n^FTT0,1400^LOGO39\n^FT0,250^LOGO39\n\n^FO165,1224^GB46,107,46^FS\n^FT202,1331^A0B,37,36^FB107,1,0,C^FR^FH\\^FD$WWW^FS\n^FT324,1569^BQN,2,7\n^FH\\^FDLA,M1JOHN HUDSON         C3JIOP  HHNAJRSR 7999 56 Y12E 12   100\\5C5E00L262562^FS\n^FT157,1546^A0B,51,50^FH\\^FD$JOHN HUDSON^FS\n^FT204,1553^A0B,25,24^FH\\^FDFROM^FS\n^FT202,1487^A0B,37,36^FH\\^FD$HNN^FS\n^FT204,1384^A0B,25,24^FH\\^FDTO^FS\n^FT71,997^A0B,39,38^FH\\^FD$Economy^FS\n^FT169,916^A0B,25,24^FH\\^FDFLIGHT NO^FS\n^FT163,797^A0B,56,48^FH\\^FD$AC $3999^FS\n^FT209,918^A0B,25,24^FH\\^FDDATE\/TIME^FS\n^FT204,793^A0B,34,33^FH\\^FD$25 FEB 2020 - $23:50^FS\n^FT273,1562^A0B,25,24^FH\\^FDSEAT^FS\n^FT285,1508^A0B,62,62^FH\\^FD$3B^FS\n^FT273,1312^A0B,25,24^FH\\^FDGATE^FS\n^FT273,1106^A0B,25,24^FH\\^FDSEQ^FS\n^FT273,838^A0B,25,24^FH\\^FDBOARDING^FS\n^FT280,1255^A0B,56,55^FH\\^FD$A1^FS\n^FT280,1044^A0B,56,55^FH\\^FD$4321^FS\n^FT280,733^A0B,56,55^FH\\^FD$22:22^FS\n^FT354,1268^A0B,25,24^FH\\^FDPCS\/WT^FS\n^FT354,1110^A0B,25,24^FH\\^FDTKNO^FS\n^FT354,868^A0B,25,24^FH\\^FDPNR^FS\n^FT354,747^A0B,25,24^FH\\^FDAGENT^FS\n^FT396,1268^A0B,28,28^FH\\^FD$17\/$18 DPCS\/WT^FS\n^FT371,407^A0B,20,19^FH\\^FDSEQ^FS\n^FT420,407^A0B,20,19^FH\\^FDTIME^FS\n^FT280,335^A0B,62,62^FH\\^FD$3B^FS\n^FT331,335^A0B,31,31^FH\\^FD$17\/$18 $kgs^FS\n^FT380,335^A0B,39,38^FH\\^FD$4321^FS\n^FT425,335^A0B,31,31^FH\\^FD$23:50^FS\n^FT483,324^A0B,31,31^FH\\^FD$AC $3999^FS\n^FT525,327^A0B,31,31^FH\\^FD$25 FEB 2020^FS\n^BY3,6^FT517,28^B7I,6,2,,,N\n^FH\\^FDM1JOHN HUDSON         C3JIOP  HHNAJRSR 7999 56 Y12E 12   100\\5C5E00L262562^FS\n^FT580,947^A0B,17,16^FH\\^FD$?ABOMIS^FS\n^FT580,250^A0B,17,16^FH\\^FD$?ABOMIS^FS\n^FT396,743^A0B,28,28^FH\\^FD$25^FS\n^FT494,1110^A0B,28,28^FH\\^FD(SSR):^FS\n^FT478,1161^A0B,17,16^FH\\^FDSpecial^FS\n^FT493,1161^A0B,17,16^FH\\^FDService^FS\n^FT508,1161^A0B,17,16^FH\\^FDRequests^FS\n^FT495,1027^A0B,31,31^FH\\^FD$SSRs^FS\n^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ,PT##?S9N#@;#TICKT#CHKIN#BOARD#01011101#0205#0330F16M#0415H07M#0513H54#0603I20L#0705I27K54L#0817D54#0903#1010D16R#1105I39L#1205I46K70L#1316F54#1418I07M#1505#1610I32K59L#1705K65L#1807#2104#2205M58L#2305N07M#2404N66R#2605M07O58R#2715O07L#2815R54L#3002P10P66#3103P13P69#3301E19#3401E19#3501E19#3601E35#3701E19#4001E19#4101E19#4201L#3215G16L#3315H15L#3405#3515#3601B02#3701D05#3820#3920#4020#4120#4220#4301#4406M13R#4520#4601C17#4720#4820#4920#5011#5105G10H54L#5203H10H63L#5305K45K63L#5405K14L#5504O10P54L#5604#5703#5816#5908O41L#6012H36L#6112G36L#6212F36L#6307#6420#6504#6619A26#6711#6813#6920#7020#7120#7220#7320#7420#7520#7620#7714K29L#7805K56L#7904O32O54L#8004P41L#8120#8220#8320#8420#8520#8620#8920#9020#FABRE012232#FBBRE012232#"
}, {
    "DeviceID": 1,
    "data": "BTT1139~H0500255=#02C0 E503250304#03B1 A494250541#04C0MI129450201#06B1 A002250541=03#11C0MA146250304=02#12B1M3150454041=03#13C0 4194372415LIMITED#14C0 B050250404LIMITTAG#20C0 1030400202#F4C0M1065350201#F5C0M1065450201#F6C0 A008220201#FEC0 1001010201#FFC0 1001010201#,^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNN^MTD^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR5,5~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ\n^XA\n^MMT\n^PW384\n^LL4156\n^LS0\n\n1----\nA\n^BY3,3,42^FT34,3817^BCN,,N,N\n^FD$6666666666^FS\nB\n^BY3,3,42^FT34,3947^BCN,,N,N\n^FD$6666666666^FS\nCTIMAJCHI^FS^CI0\n^FT137,1062^A@I,25,24,TT0003M_^FH\\^CI17^F8^FD0025^FS^CI0\n^FT357,1097^A0I,28,45^FH\\^FDLH 0492^FS\n^FT137,1102^A@I,25,24,TT0003M_^FH\\^CI17^F8^FD$DATE^FS^CI0\n^FO104,1134^GB177,56,56^FS\n^FT281,1145^A0I,45,45^FR^FH\\^FD$ALName^FS\n^FT277,1203^A@I,31,31,TT0003M_^FH\\^CI17^F8^FD9999999999^FS^CI0\n^FT25,2352^A@N,25,24,TT0003M_^FH\\^CI17^F8^FD$FromName^FS^CI0\n^FO83,2836^GB214,46,46^FS\n^FT83,2872^A@N,31,47,TT0003M_^FR^FH\\^CI17^F8^FDTEXT: -----^FS^CI0\n^FO1,2819^GB380,0,4^FS\n^FO1,2668^GB380,0,2^FS\n^FO1,2530^GB380,0,2^FS\n^FO1,2371^GB380,0,2^FS\n^FT27,2694^A@N,25,24,TT0003M_^FH\\^CI17^F8^FDVIA2:^FS^CI0\n^FT27,2562^A@N,25,24,TT0003M_^FH\\^CI17^F8^FDVIA1:^FS^CI0"
}]
```

As you see the `Data` tag does not look like an array.

I tried `json_query` but was not successful.

Comment: What does the source data look like? Why does it self join on Id? You should make it easy for people to help you by supplying table definitions and insert statements so people don't have to mock this up themselves

Comment: Have you tried using `JSON_QUERY()` to wrap a subquery that itself produces JSON output? That's usually how you get JSON arrays in SQL Server.

Comment: @MartinSmith : I added the table source script and a sample from my source data. also the join is not necessary because i have all data in 1 table. I  just wrote it with join to try if it works, Your help will be appreciate.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: I did the same but the result will be as bellow.
[{
    "DeviceID": 0,
    "data": [{"test"
]}, {
    "DeviceID": 1,
    "data": {["test"
]}}

Comment: Your `ID` column is defined as `IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY`, so how do you expect to self-join on it to return multiple values for the `Data` JSON property? It can only ever return one row (and so one array value). How do you actually need to gather those multiple values shown in your desired output?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: the join is not necessary in the query .only the right json is important for me.  we can write the query as bellow :
SELECT 
    DeviceID = CASE
                   WHEN pd.Type IN ( 'BP', 'MD' ) THEN 0
                   ELSE 1
               END,
    STRING_AGG(pd.Data, ',')data
FROM
    Setting.PrinterData AS pd

WHERE  
    pd.isDeleted = 0
    AND pd.al = 'ZZ'
GROUP BY 
    CASE
        WHEN pd.Type IN ( 'BP', 'MD' ) THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END 
FOR JSON AUTO